# Сохранение звука с google translate

Tags: java, android, google-translate

В гугла есть апи для работы с переводчиком (https://translate.google.com.ua/), но я нигде не могу найти метод для получения ссылки на озвучку введенного текста. В самом переводчике такая возможность есть и звук воспроизводится нажатием на кнопку (на фото видно). Кто-то делал делал получение аудио по апи либо другим способом?

Интересует реализация под андроид.
[image: google translate]

Comment: Там не ссылка, вы что. Эта кнопка просто воспроизводит аудио по тексту. В Android это можно реализовать через Google TTS.

Comment: если вы имеете в виде данный класс android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech, то у него озвучка зависит от самого устройства, версии андроид и может сильно отличатся. Нужно что-бы на всех устройствах было одинаковое воспроизведение. Если вы имели в виду другой клас, то прошу уточнить

Comment: А как насчет декомпиляции Google Translater? Там есть кнопка для воспроизведения

Comment: я пока еще не делал этого. сомниваюсь что гул не позаботился о защите своего приложения

Comment: Можно заглянуть в devtools браузера, посмотреть на какой адрес что отсылается и сделать класс, который будет эмулировать запрос туда. Как пример `https://translate.google.ru/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=test&tl=en&total=1&idx=0&textlen=4&tk=474843.89142&client=t&prev=input&ttsspeed=0.24`, где, как можно видеть, есть параметр `q=test` для слова.... Правда надо решить проблему с генерированием `tk`

Comment: я уже пробовал сделать такое, но не получилось. попробуйте заменить test на другое слово и получите 403.

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych потому что там генерируется `tk`, как я сразу об этом написал. Вы не внимательны. Можно посмотреть некие библиотеки на github (типа https://github.com/hungtruong/Google-Translate-TTS/blob/master/GoogleTTS.py или https://github.com/Goodlookinguy/FFMediaCacheGrabber) и сделать что-то похожее для себя. Я когда-то делал, но что-то не могу найти

Comment: А вообще, емнип, достаточно зарегистрироваться и пользоваться апи. тогда дадут доступ. хотя вроде это платно :(

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych Нашел. В свое время я использовал вот это: https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php  .... точнее я использовал непосредственно класс `GoogleTokenGenerator` оттуда, который как раз помогает генерировать нужный токен. Можете попробовать его или еще поискать что-то, что поможет токен генерировать ;-)

Comment: Ну и напоследок совет. У гугл транслейта ужасное воспроизведение слов. Там на столько кривая озвучка, что иногда непонятно что за слово, звуки съедаются, неправильно произносятся, и вообще там британский английский. Я бы рекомендовал для звуков найти нормальные сайты для изучения английского, где есть воспроизведение звуков и брать их там...например http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/test  - звук http://www.ldoceonline.com/media/english/ameProns/test1.mp3  - и никаких токенов не нужно

Answer (score -1):

Нельзя скачивать, запишите звук какой то программой.